# Is it possible to use a List in Google Sheets via the OR() function during a comparison (test)?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, logic, gs-conditional-formatting

Specifically in regards to conditional formatting, but also applicable in the broader scope of `IF()` tests within Google Sheets...

Can I compare using `=IF(A1=OR("Yes","Y","YES"))` and achieve the same result as `=IF(OR(A1="Yes"),(A1="Y"),(A1="YES"))`? I know that both expressions could be simplified by removing the leading `IF()`, but since I'm desiring to use this information in the context of conditional formatting.

*I know* that the above two statements do not evaluate identically. Is there different (and simpler) syntax that the verbose `OR(<full-expression>,<full-expression>,etc...)`, or am I stuck with that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a little more searching under a *different* question yielded the answer to this one: [`REGEXMATCH()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292).

`=REGEXMATCH(A1,"Yes|Y|YES")` evaluates the same as `=IF(OR(A1="Yes"),(A1="Y"),(A1="YES"))`. Note: Per the above-linked page, Google products use [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt) for regular expressions.